# Google Developer Tools Java FATAL ERROR

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am new to the `Google developer tools` and I have been messing around trying to figure out how to get one of their features to work.

This one most specifically:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse#Running_the_Project

So this is how far I've gotten.

I updated my `Java package to 1.7`. I installed the `Google plug in` for `eclipse`.,

I created a new project named "`Guestbook`", made sure the boxes were checked, `run->DebugAs-> WebApplication`, and then I get this huge **error**:

> Exception in thread "main" FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of
>   -javaagent failed java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/appengine/tools/development/agent/AppEngineDevAgent :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
>   sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:280)
>     at
>   sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:338)

I don't know what all this means.

I am still fairly new to java, so any help would be excellent.

Hope all is well

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using Java7 for running the application as well?

Comment: yeah I did this:  MacBook-Pro:~ macbookpro$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: Ok, can you run the app from the terminal itself? The reason I ask this is because it is possible that Eclipse is still using the Java6 (Apple provided) for running the dev server. So try to run the app from the terminal to rule out that possibility.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure how to run it from the terminal. All this is new to me and haven't used a terminal since I was learning C. I did some looking and as it turns out Eclipse is still running 1.6. I went into the Execution Environments, clicked on JavaSE-1.7, and in the panel on the right it should say "jdk1.7.0[perfect match] with a little box to check to make it my default JDK, but there is nothing there...

Comment: Go it, this is what I had to do to allow eclipse to access the JDK: Project>Properties>Java Build Path>Add Library>JRE System Library>Installed JREs>Add

Comment: You are welcome. Can you add that as an answer so that it can help others who have a similar problem?